# How to search for a single word in multiple gvim files from the command line?

Tags: linux, unix, vim

I want to open up multiple files in different tabs and search for the same word in all of them. Then I want to jump to the first occurrence of the found word in each file.

Doing this works, but it doesn't jump to the first occurrence:

```
gvim -p -cmd "/word" file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7
```

I need to manually press 'n' to go to the next match.

Answer (score 1):

Vim doesn't provide a way to execute a command for every file on the command line.  The `-c` option causes the command to be executed after the *first* file is read, and `--cmd` happens before any files are opened.

If you want to do this, you'd probably need to define a script with a function that did that (say, `Search`), load the script with `-S`, and then execute it with `--remote-send` option.  On many systems, `gvim` starts up with a default server name by default, but if it doesn't, you'd need to use `--servername` with your initial process.

Alternatively, you could do this from the command line with `grep`, which would be more flexible, but of course wouldn't appear in an editor.

Comment: "> The -c option causes the command to be executed after the *first* file is read…" But the command could be `argdo` or `bufdo`. I often run `vim -c "set nomore" -c "argdo %s/search/replace/" -c xa`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're opening the files in separate tab pages, you can use [`:help :tabdo`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#%3Atabdo) to execute the search in every page.

If it's okay to just go to the *line* of the first match, you can directly do the search via `:/`:

```
vim -p -c 'tabdo /word/' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7
```

To also go to the beginning of the first match within the line, we need something like this, using normal mode `n`:

```
vim -p -c "/word" -c 'tabdo 1normal! n' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in `:grep` and `:vimgrep`, which populate the quickfix list:

```
$ gvim file*
:vimgrep /pattern/ ##
```

The `##` means search the argument list, which you can view with `:args`. It’s what `:next` and `:prev` use.

Now, you can navigate the searches with `:cnext` and `:cprev`; or, you can open the quickfix window `:copen` and hit enter on any line.

You could still pop open all the files in tabs with `:cfdo tabedit` but at this point it might not be necessary!